# Problem with a laggy application using threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

It is my understanding (please correct me if i'm way off the mark) that my using threads correctly will allow an application to seem to multitask despite high processor load.

In my application I have a thread in which I process images taken from the camera preview and attempt to do real-time face detection with a great deal of success. The problem lies when at the same time as this I want to be able to have a button on the screen which can be pressed and some action taken without any relation to what is going on to the camera detection methods.

The problem is the face detection is pretty quick, but when I go to press the button it takes a good second or so to respond to this. Without the face detection thread being activated (i.e. the start() method never being called) the button is very quick. Below is a stripped version of my code as it's too long just to post straight as it is:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        faceThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                //Get camera preview image and detect faces
            }
        });
        faceThread.start();
    }

public void onClickShoot(View v) throws InterruptedException,
            media = new MediaPlayer();
    media.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            media.stop();
            media.reset();
        }
    });
    media.setDataSource(this, dataPath);
    media.prepare();
    media.start();
            //And some other stuff here too.

    }
```

Is it just a limitation that I have this delay on the fact it's a mobile platform and i'm expecting too much? Or is there a way of making this work? I'f you need more info about what i'm doing please just ask :).

**Edit (more code to address problem):**

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
                    public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {
                        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                        int format = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
                        // YUV formats require more conversion
                        if (format == ImageFormat.NV21) {
                            int w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
                            int h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
                            // Get the YuV image
                            YuvImage yuv_image = new YuvImage(_data, format, w, h, null);
                            // Convert YuV to Jpeg
                            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w/3, h); // Rect of the image in which to search for the face
                            final ByteArrayOutputStream output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            yuv_image.compressToJpeg(rect, 10, output_stream);
                            // Convert from Jpeg to Bitmap
                            detectFaces(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                                    output_stream.toByteArray(), 0,
                                    output_stream.size()));
                            Log.v("TEST", "TEST");
                        }
                    }
                });


public void detectFaces(Bitmap bmp) {
        FaceView faceView = new FaceView(this, bmp);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to determine where the contention is. Is it for CPU time, or is it for some other resource? It might help to do some profiling... Tim Bray recently wrote a good introduction to how and why to do this here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/10/traceview-war-story.html

For what it's worth `MediaPlayer` is notoriously slow and heavyweight. What media are you giving it? Are you giving it a stream or buffer that's mostly in memory, or will it be doing tons of I/O to read media over the network or from storage?

Out of interest, why do you need face detection once the button has been pressed? Maybe you could stop the thread before starting up the media player?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the contention is for CPU time as the face detection and the mediaPlayer don't sahre any resources other than a very small image. The media is a very small .wav file which is stored in the raw folder in the resources so no heavyweight streaming. The face detection needs to be started again immediately after the sound has played, I tried using a wait(100) call on the thread but didn't change the fact that there was the delay. Is their much gain stopping the thread over making it wait?

Comment: Is the .wav a sort of camera shutter noise, by any chance? Whatever it is, you are loading it from storage... that's always going to take time. Suggest you load it in the background, when the activity starts up, so it's ready to just play() immediately.

Comment: More importantly, don't guess where the contention is... it's oh-so-easy to be surprised as to what's really happening underneath all those APIs. Use the profiling tools to go and find out! :-)  If your face detection thread isn't doing any IO it might still not be CPU contention. What sort of synchronization is it using to access your pixel buffer? Maybe it acquires a lock on that buffer 1000s of times per second, forcing your UI thread to wait a lot? The devil is always in the details I'm afraid...

Comment: It's actually a gunshot which is only on for about 100ms. I ran the trace from the link you provided and it does seem it's the face detection using 75% of the CPU time, every 400ms it takes 330ms for the face detection. It seems the button only comes into play when the cycle for the face detection is complete. I don't think I can have the media player set up at first because I require the play to be rapid, so it's possible it could be playing 2 instances at once. I am using the onPreviewFrame to get the image for the face detection if that is what you mean by the synchronization?

Comment: Your face detection must need to read the contents of a buffer that is (presumably) being filled by another thread. There will be synchronization in there somewhere to prevent the buffer being written while it is being read, and vice versa. I don't understand why you have to create your MediaPlayer only in response to the button press... surely you want it as early as possible so it's ready to play when the button is pressed.

Comment: How can I find out what synchronization is being used? My thoughts about the media player was each button press needs it's own media player because I want to allow them to overlap, so if the button is pressed twice in quick succession then the 2 sounds are played with a bit of overlap. Even initialising the mediaplayer in the onCreate does not solve the lagging issue though. I have my image I want to detect the face on as small as possible now, being a bitmap too it would be pointless trying to reduce the quality, maybe I could reduce the resolution?

Comment: Use a SoundPool then, if you need more than one sound. The *only* thing you want to do in your button onClick is play() the preloaded sound. What face recognition library are you using?

Comment: I am just using a FaceDetector object that comes with the SDK and pass it a bitmap created from the camera preview periodically, from the method onPreviewFrame() of the Camera object. This returns a byte array which is converted to a YUV image, compressed to a jpeg, converted to the bitmap used to detect the face.

Comment: I had no idea there was a FaceDetector in the SDK! You certainly don't want to be compressing and decompressing to jpeg... that's pointless and very expensive. Tell Camera preview to use an RGB format.

Comment: The method to output the image only outputs it as a byte array which represents a YUV image. Which from what I found it is best to convert to Jpeg then use BitmapFactory to convert to bitmap. From the trace I did earlier compared to the actual face detect is not very expensive. The detection is pretty quick, it's just that it seems to lock everything else out until it has completed its next cycle before addressing the button press.

Comment: Software jpeg encoding is very expensive. FaceDetector won't be working on compressed data... what on earth is the point of compressing it to jpeg (very expensive) and then decompressing it again (merely expensive), when you're not doing anything that requires compression? YUV probably *is* a good format for face detection, since I doubt that algorithm has much use for colour, but the jpeg compression is totally pointless and best avoided. Can you post some code?

Comment: I have added the code used to generate the image to perform the face detection upon, I'm not sure is you would like to see the FaceView.java class code I have left a little bit out of this because there is quite a bit of code but basically in creating the faceView object I set a boolean if a face is found and that changed a red box green.

Comment: The findFaces() API states that "The bitmap must be in 565 format (for now)." I guarantee that if you respect this statement, and use setPreviewFormat() when you set up your camera to enforce it - and lose all that totally pointless JPEG compression & decompression - your performance will be greatly improved.